# Terminate an Lwt thread from another thread

Tags: tcp, ocaml, ocaml-lwt, lwt

Here I have a function which accept a TCP connection and run two Lwt threads `handle_connection` and `send_message`. Each time that a connection is terminated I am notified in the `handle_connection` thread, so I can terminate it loops, but then I want to terminate the whole join `<&>` thread to go further with another connection in the next `serv` recursive call.

```ml
let create_server sock =
  let rec serve () =
    Lwt_unix.accept sock
    >>= (fun (fd, _) ->
          connection := true;
          let ic = Lwt_io.of_fd ~mode:Lwt_io.Input fd in
          let oc = Lwt_io.of_fd ~mode:Lwt_io.Output fd in
          handle_connection ic oc <&> send_message oc)
    >>= serve
  in
  serve ()
```

The question is, how can I force the `send_message` thread to terminate each time that `handle_connection` terminates ?

```ml
let handle_connection ic oc =
  Lwt.on_failure (handle_message ic oc "client") (fun e ->
      Logs.err (fun m -> m "%s" (Printexc.to_string e)));
  Logs_lwt.info (fun m -> m "New connection")


let rec send_message oc =
  let* s = read_console () in
  Lwt_io.write_line oc s >>= fun _ -> send_message oc)
```

I have already tried to use `Lwt.choose` instead of `Lwt.join`, it passes to the next connection when client is disconnected but the `send_message` thread is still running on the terminated connection.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm not familiar with `Lwt`, but if `>>=` and `return` are the usual monad operators, `>>= return` should be useless, by monad laws.

Comment: @BlackBeans I use that to return a value of the Lwt monad type.
Lwt.return : 'a -> 'a Lwt.t
creates a promise which is already fulfilled with the given value

Comment: Have you tried simply removing it? `(>>=) : 'a Lwt.t -> ('a -> 'b Lwt.t) -> 'b`, so it means you already had a promise (it should still typecheck).

Comment: That's write thank you, I will update the expression.

Answer (score 1):

I hesitate to comment on this as I suspect that you already know this, but as a matter of general principle the most fundamental way in which you conditionally wait on a promise in Lwt is to construct the promise using `Lwt.wait`, and then bind on the promise using operator `let*` or operator `>>=` until the promise's resolver either fulfils the promise by means of `Lwt.wakeup_later` or (in your special case) rejects it using `Lwt.wakeup_later_exn`.  Alternatively in the latter case you could construct the promise using `Lwt.task` and reject the promise directly by cancellation with `Lwt.cancel`, but I believe cancellation is now deprecated or at least discouraged.

There is a `Lwt.pick` function which, on a promise being fulfilled, will cancel any others which are bound by the pick, but that is the inverse of what you want.  What this means is that I think you are going to have to restructure your code to expose the conditional promise.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried to use `task` and `pick` but my problem is that I want a running promise until it is cancelled by some event (in another function), and then it runs again with some other event.
With task, I can only `cancel` or `wakeup` it once if I understood the concept well.
Maybe you can show me how can I achieve this with a piece of code, please ?

Comment: Yes, you can only fulfil or reject any one promise once.  To do what you want you will have to apply `Lwt.wait` or `Lwt.task` on each iteration.

Comment: On a different point, send_message is waiting for the promise returned by read_console to be resolved. You don't give the implementation of the latter function, but presumably that is the promise that you need to reject or cancel.

Comment: Note also that a "thread" in Lwt is just a series of dependent promises: it is not like an OS thread.  By rejecting or canceling the promise whose continuation is currently bound by operator `let*` or operator `>>=`, that "thread" goes away.

Comment: If instead of having a global `task`, I create a `task` on each iteration in one function, then I can not give it to another function to cancel it later. How can we resolve this problem ?

Comment: You could use a global reference.  But could you not pass the promise or its resolver as a function argument?

Comment: The functions don't call each other, so I can not pass the promise as an argument !

Comment: I still feel that I haven't fully grasped your use case.  You should treat cancelling a promise representing a chain of dependent promises, or rejecting it via its resolver, in a similar way to the way you would if applying pthread_cancel to the thread ID of a native OS thread.  If that requires a global thread ID (or here a global reference) so be it: but I suspect your code could be restructured to avoid that.  You would of course have to handle the rejection, if necessary by doing nothing, but that is straightforward with `Lwt.catch` or the `try%lwt` macro.